# How to occupy all the days in fullCalendar?

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-3

A query for those who have used fullCalendar. I use version 3 of fullCalendar.

I have the dates (the step without hour:minute) start `2020-06-01` end `2020-06-03`

But I'm only occupying 2 days as seen in the picture, instead of 3 days [1,3]. I don't know why this happens.

[image]

I understand that by default you may be taking the time as 00:00 and this is giving "that problem".

The question would then be, if you need a configuration that takes the full day on the last day, and I don't know if such a configuration will exist?

Answer (score 0):

This is covered in the documentation. End dates are **exclusive** - see https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/event-object .

This means your event is actually considered to end at 2020-06-02 23:59:59. Therefore it doesn't actually occur on 2020-06-03 and so is not shown on that date.

The workaround, if you wish to show it on that day, is to add one day to your end date.